# I'm having some trouble working with dates on my application that uses SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm having some trouble working with dates on my application that uses SQLite.
This is my table which include date datatype
1.
I select fromdate and todate from dialog picker and while I click on show button I got an error which listed below:

```
Process: com.example.patidar.datedb, PID: 2471 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Oct": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select * from NewDATE where DATE BETWEEN Tue Oct 10 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017 AND Thu Oct 26 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017
```

This is the `onCreate` method from my Database helper:-

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+ TBNAME +" ( "+ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+DATE+" date,"+NAME+" TEXT)";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}
```

I am retrieving date by using below method in `DBHelper` class. Here I put all code

```
 public ArrayList<ADate> retrieveByUseDate(String fromdate,String todate) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    Date date1 = sfd.parse(fromdate);
    Date date2 = sfd.parse(todate);

    SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<ADate> arrayList = new ArrayList<ADate>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from " + TBNAME + " where DATE BETWEEN " + date1+ " AND " + date2, null);
    System.out.println(cursor);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String selectdate = cursor.getString(1);
        String aname = cursor.getString(2);
        ADate date = new ADate(id, selectdate, aname);
        arrayList.add(date);
    }
    return arrayList;
}
```

I used Datepicker dialog for retrieve date from calendar in activity class

```
public class RetrieveData extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button btnFromDate,btnToDate,btnshow;
ListView lvRecord;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrieve_data);
    btnFromDate= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFromDate);
    btnToDate= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnToDate);
    btnshow= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
    lvRecord= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRecord);
    btnFromDate.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnToDate.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnshow.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btnFromDate:
            fromDate();
            break;
        case R.id.btnToDate:
            toDate();
            break;
        case R.id.btnShow:              
            try {
                dateRecord();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
    }
}

public void fromDate(){
    Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();

    final int yr=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    DatePickerDialog dd=new DatePickerDialog(RetrieveData.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            String date=i+"-"+(i1+1)+"-"+i2;
                btnFromDate.setText(date);
        }
    },yr,month,day);
    dd.show();
}

public void toDate(){
    Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
    final int yr=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dd=new DatePickerDialog(RetrieveData.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            String date=i+"-"+(i1+1)+"-"+i2;
            btnToDate.setText(date);
        }
    },yr,month,day);
    dd.show();
}

public void dateRecord() throws ParseException {

    String fromdate=btnFromDate.getText().toString();
    String todate=btnToDate.getText().toString();

    DBHelper db=new DBHelper(RetrieveData.this);
    ArrayList<ADate> aDateArrayList=db.retrieveByUseDate(fromdate,todate);
    ArrayAdapter<ADate> aDateArrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<ADate>(RetrieveData.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,aDateArrayList);
    lvRecord.setAdapter(aDateArrayAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate the issues....

Comment: You don't ask any questions, you just pasted your code

Comment: you ony showed the code, and didn't ask any questions. What is the problem?

Comment: What is the problem you were faced? Don't put just a code.

Comment: My date is not consider as simple date format("yyyy-MM-dd") it takes a date  like 'Tue Oct 10 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017' in this format and I add date in database "yyyy-MM-dd" using calendar control.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a DatePicker that gets the date and styles it to look like this 10-20-2017 also if the date is only 7 or 6 characters long it adds zeros "0" first then the dashes if you did not add the dashes all dates would look like this 02032017 this format is ideal for storage but not to look at hence the adding of dashes We will post the date picker code AND the code to remove the dashes before you add the date back to the database

Date Picker this picker lives in its own XML file will post the XML as well

```
    public void findByDate(){
    etPurchaseDate.setText("");
    // DATE PICKER Sub Routine the XML file holds the Date Picker see 
  datepickerview.xml
    final Dialog dialog = new 
  Dialog(DetailsActivity.this,R.style.DatePickerTheme);
    /* the style and reference to the XML MUST be included in the lines os 
  code above and below */
    /* 

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.datepickerview);
    dialog.setTitle("");
    DatePicker picker = dialog.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    picker.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);// Keeps Calendar initial view to 
  what today is!

    picker.init(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
  c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker picker, int year, int 
  monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            String searchFrom = (String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1)) + 
   (String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)) + String.valueOf(year);
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(searchFrom);
            if (searchFrom.length() == 7) {
                    str.insert(2, '0');
                    str.insert(2, '-');
                    str.insert(5, '-');
                    etPurchaseDate.setText(str);
                } else if (searchFrom.length() == 6) {
                    str.insert(0, '0');
                    str.insert(2, '0');
                    str.insert(2, '-');
                    str.insert(5, '-');
                    etPurchaseDate.setText(str);
                } else {
                    etPurchaseDate.setText(searchFrom);
                    etPurchaseDate.requestFocus();
                    etPurchaseDate.setSelection(8);
                }
                etCost.requestFocus();
                dialog.dismiss();
        }
});
    dialog.show();
}
for date picker xml

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/color_White"
   android:orientation="vertical">

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:calendarViewShown="true"
    android:headerBackground="@color/color_Purple"
    android:theme="@style/DatePickerTheme" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Use this code to strip the dashes before you save the data

```
            if(etPurchaseDate.length()==10) {
                            /* NO spaces \ No = \ NO - \ NO -- \ ONLY 
    numbers \ NO - at the end*/
                String tstr = "^(?!.*\\s)^(?=.*)^(?!-)(?!.*--)[0-9-]+(?
    <!-)$";
                String astr = etPurchaseDate.getText().toString().trim();
                Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(tstr);
                Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(astr);

                boolean foundMatch = regexMatcher.find();


      if (foundMatch == true ) {//IF FOUND REMOVE THE DASH'S AND STORE DATA
 /* Routine puts DATE back in DB as 8 Character String REMOVES dashes "-" */
                    StringBuilder removeTHIS = new 
     StringBuilder(etPurchaseDate.getText().toString());
                    String value = removeTHIS.toString().replace("-", "");
                    etPurchaseDate.setText(value);
                    etCost.requestFocus();
                    purchase_date = value;
                    etCost.requestFocus();
                    //return;
                    Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, "Date was Formatted 
       for Storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```